# Eclipse changes not reflected in output

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been using Eclipse for several years without issue.  I made changes to my java code as recently as last week without problem.  Now, I have tried to make changes to my code and they are not reflected when I run the code.  One example (and there are several) is I changed the URL I am trying to hit.  I have a print statement to verify the variable is getting the correct information.  It still reflects the old code.

I thought something may be cached somewhere, so I booted the server, but the problem persists.  I tried removing some old projects just in case there was corruption from them, but the problem persists.  There are a couple of references to this happening to others, but they always involve Tomcat or some other app I'm not using.  My setup is just eclipse with java.  My version is Mars.2 Release 4.5.2.

Comment: Theres a flag in the menu Project > Build automaticaly, make sure it is checked also, not sure if it disable building when running, else you would need to manually build (Ctrl+3 ... Build ... enter)

Comment: Thank you. I verified that it remains checked.  I was hoping for an easy solution.

Comment: Use your sourcecodeversioning tool to see if any project related file was changed

Comment: I have never used a source code versioning tool.  Judging from what I've read online, it would be too late for that to help me, right? Do you have a recommendation for one going forward?

Comment: Too late for checking for modifications, but if you want to learn more would go with github that uses git or gitlab that has private repos (uses git too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what became corrupted.  I attempted 
1. export projects to a .zip file. 
2. delete the workspace 
3. open eclipse 
4. close eclipse 
5. open eclipse 
6. import projects

This did not resolve the issue.  Someone asked for the code where I see the problem.  It was several places, but one example is

```
 //     String fileURL = "ftp://www.websiteIDoNotWant" + path;
        String fileURL = "http://websiteIDoWant" + path;
        System.out.println("FileDownloader, fileURL: " + fileURL);
```

The output I got was FileDownloader, fileURLftp://www.websiteIDoNotWant/2012/020/rkpt/rkpt0200.12d.Z

So, what ended up working was creating a new Maven project with new classes and copying the code one class at a time and pasting it into the new project. 
Whatever was caching the old code is not present in the new project.  I will delete the old one and move forward.

Comment: You again said maven :p

Comment: And I meant it.  I made this one a maven project.  All my newer code is, which is why I assumed the one I was looking at was Maven.  I didn't remember when I adopted using Maven all those years ago.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

1. Do a `maven build clean install` and see if build is able to finish successfully.
2. Do `maven>Update` project.
3. try clearing off all the pre-built files (.class files and everything) inside the server's root folder and re-publish the project.

If all the above mentioned steps are successful and still you are not able to resolve the error, I guess cleaning your local .m2 folder and re-building everything from scratch might help.

Caching of java `.class` files is a pain. It happens with me everyday and is all because my .class files are kept cached inside the tcServer and whenever I restart, the same files get picked up. Cleaning those files will force eclipse to re-compile all the java files and when you build and publish them to the tcServer, they'll get replaced.

Comment: I'm working on step 1.  I looked up a video about how to do that and he starts out right clicking on the pom file.  I do not have one on the project I'm having problems with.  Does that mean it's not using Maven?

Comment: Well you added a tag for maven and I have never worked on any maven project which doesn't have a pom file.
Try clearing the root directly directly in your case. Just remove the project from the server, clean the root directory, start the server, stop it again, add the project and finally start it again. Trust me that works.

Comment: I'm sorry about the Maven tag.  I initially created these years ago and mistakenly thought they were all Maven projects.  This one predates me finding Maven.  Just to be sure of your instructions...1. export projects to a .zip file.  2. delete the workspace  3. open eclipse  4. close eclipse  5. open eclipse  6. import projects.  I followed these steps, but it's still running the old version.  If you mean something different by "clean the root directory" then I have misunderstood.

Comment: You are using tomcat server right? There is a root directory inside your tomcat server from which your application runs. Please open that and clear all the class files. Deleting workspace won't help because your class files are stuck inside the tcServer. The delting and re-running everything was for the server, and not for eclipse. I hope I was clear :)

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not using Tomcat.  I run it directly from eclipse until I get it running well - then I make a java applet and let windows scheduler hit it.

Comment: Can you try clearing the bin folder? Are you sure you are executing the correct class file only? And your changes are properly saved?

Comment: How, *exactly*, are you running it directly from Eclipse? In what way are you changing the URL? Can you show us the code that you expect to behave differently? Spare no details.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Marcos to enable "Project > Build automaticaly" helped me. It was automatically disabled during a recent update, I spent so much time trying to find out the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30655576)

Answer (score 0):

Change settings to **Save automatically before build**
in Eclipse,

- Click Window > Preferences.
- Select General > Workspace from the list.
- Workspace > Select Save automatically before build check box & Build automatically.
- Apply and Close

Also, do this
**The auto-save is disabled by default**

- General -> Editors -> Enable autsave for dirty editors

This saves automatically at regular intervals, say for example, 20s